# How to verify that every object within an S3 bucket has been encrypted through boto3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, encryption, boto3

[AWS recently announced that all S3 data will be encrypted by default with no way to turn it off.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/bucket-encryption.html)  Great. However, I have a need to programmically verify that older data is also encrypted within S3.

I know that you can set a policy for everything to be encrypted and can programmically check the policy (as per [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55718828/boto3-aws-check-if-s3-bucket-is-encrypted)).

But that just tells you what encryption will be going forward. How do we tell if there are things currently not encrypted or whether everything is encrypted?

Answer (score 1):

In general, you can't easily determine if an object's contents were encrypted outside of AWS before uploading to S3, but you can easily determine if individual objects have been encrypted server-side by S3.

To do the latter, there are a couple of options:

1. get an S3 [inventory report](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/storage-inventory.html), which will include each object's encryption status (SSE-S3, SSE-C, SSE-KMS, or NOT-SSE)
2. enumerate the Bucket's [objects](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3/bucket/objects.html) using boto3, and test the [server_side_encryption](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3/object/server_side_encryption.html) property on each object